# Is there a better wording option for "at the moment"?

Tags: word-request

I'm trying to find a better synonym for "at the moment". I found "currently" and "at present". However, they don't sound better than "at the moment" in my sentence, which is:

> At the moment, our ERP system is on AWS.

Are there alternatives to "at the moment" in this sentence?

I don't want to be limited only to use this wording every time. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: I would disagree that _currently_ 'doesn't sound better'. In my opinion it is the best option for a technical statement.

Comment: I see. Yes, I can't give any reason why it didn't sound better. I think it was just an impression.